# Symfony : Why put assets in web/ diectory instead of bundle's Resources/public/?

Tags: symfony, assets

I always thought symfony is one of the best PHP Framework because it uses bundles : all files are grouped in the bundle folder : views, controller, assets, so I can create severals web sites with one symfony installation (like Wordpress Multi-site) ... But I found this in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) :

> Best Practice : Store your assets in the web/ directory.

It means files are no more grouped ! Can some one explain me what are the advantages ?

I also read Sensio will perhaps no longer use bundles !! Why ???

Comment: for the same reason we don't use Assetic anymore

Comment: reasons are explained under that quote. read them and you'll understand why :)

Answer (score 0):

If the assets are bundle specific, you can use then under the bundle. `web` directory is the end-user facing root and referencing assets in an website / API from your bundle to the end-user is not suggested from security point of view.

So, even if you have your assets under `Resources/public/` directory. You have to run the command `asset:install` to install those assets to `web/bundles` directory. This will help the bundle to make compatible with plug and play feature across the application.